# Powerset o a set(list) in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the next predicate which will generate all subsets from a lists:

```
candidate([],[]).
candidate([H|T],[H|R]):-
    candidate(T,R).
candidate([_|T],R):-
    candidate(T,R).
```

Can somebody help me understand how it works? It looks so short but the recurrence behind it feels complicated to be understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to see that the only subset of `{}` is `{}`.

```
candidate([], []).
```

Suppose you want to generate all subsets of the set `S = {a,b,c}`.

Then, you can remove an element from `S` (say element `a`), obtaining the set `S-{a} = {b,c}`.

By the induction hypothesis, you can generate all subsets of `{b,c}`, which are
`{}`, `{b}`, `{c}`, `{b,c}`. That is done by the goal `candidate(T, R)`.

Since every subset of `{b,c}` is also a subset of `{a,b,c}`, you can conclude that the subsets of `S = {a,b,c}` are:

- `{}`, `{b}`, `{c}`, `{b,c}` (`candidate([_|T],R) :- candidate(T,R)`),

and also these same subsets joined with the set `{a}`, i.e.:

- `{a}`, `{a,b}`, `{a,c}`, `{a,b,c}` (`candidate([H|T],[H|R]) :- candidate(T,R)`).

By altering the order of the two recursive rules, you can see this more clearly.

```
candidate([], []).
candidate([_|T], R):- candidate(T, R).     % does not include first element
candidate([H|T], [H|R]):- candidate(T,R).  % do include first element
```

Result:

```
?- candidate([a,b,c],S).
S = [] ;
S = [c] ;
S = [b] ;
S = [b, c] ;
S = [a] ;
S = [a, c] ;
S = [a, b] ;
S = [a, b, c].
```